# Does an uninstall/reinstall usually fix bugs in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I heard that some people experienced success in uninstalling and reinstalling the PC version to fix bugs.  Would the same apply to the Xbox One version?

Comment: It really depends on what type of bugs you're talking about.

Comment: [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262010/why-wont-my-companions-react-to-the-correct-actions-at-all) and [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263757/permanent-and-unprovoked-bos-hostility)

Comment: In that case, the reinstall _may_ help for the companion reactions (given I'm not sure what the mechanics are behind the approval system atm), but almost certainly not for the BoS hostility issue (that's going to be in your save data).

Comment: @pushasha Yup. The reinstall did absolutely nothing. Pardon me for asking, but has patch come/will come out soon/recently for consoles? Sorry, my internet access is very limited.. 

Comment: Patch 1.5 came out last week on consoles, but it doesn't specifically address any of the issues you've specifically asked about. However, the GECK/mod support for consoles is likely coming out later this month, so you may be able to find a mod that will fix your issues relatively soon.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information, I look forward to the upcoming mod support. ^^

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

During installation, as the process is complex, it is entirely possible that something would go wrong. Moreover the game makes minor changes to the system, in relation to itself, so deleting the game will revert those changes, and having a fresh installation may fix some problems.

This is especially true if you have installed Mods.

Similarly to how a windows Reinstallation fixes pretty much everything wrong with your PC and is recommended every now and then.